# Installing MariaDB along with MySQL: Could not find mysqld

Tags: centos, database, mariadb

I am following the instruction on the MariaDB site [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-alongside-mysql/) all is fine until I get to the part shown below.

```
[root@squir scripts]# mysql_install_db --defaults-file=/mariadb/data/my.cnf

FATAL ERROR: Could not find mysqld

The following directories were searched:

    /mariadb/mariadb/libexec
    /mariadb/mariadb/sbin
    /mariadb/mariadb/bin

If you compiled from source, you need to run 'make install' to
copy the software into the correct location ready for operation.

If you are using a binary release, you must either be at the top
level of the extracted archive, or pass the --basedir option
pointing to that location.
```

I wonder if there is the problem with the directory structure that is confusing the install. The documentation is also old, so I am not sure if there is a step missing.

**What I Have done So far**

1. Downloaded the MariaDB.tar.gz
2. Created a directory called /mariadb/
3. Extracted the MariaDB.tar.gz and created a symbolic link called mariadb
4. Created a user group and username for MariaDB directory
5. Created /mariadb/data for storing MariaDB data file (Database)
6. Copy the pre-written configuration file by this command.

   cp mariadb/support-files/my-medium.cnf mariadb/data/my.cnf
7. Edited the my.cnf file as per instructed in [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-alongside-mysql/)

   [client]
   port        = 3307
   socket      = /mariadb/data/mariadb.sock

   [mysqld]
   datadir     = /mariadb/data
   basedir     = /mariadb/mariadb
   port    = 3307
   socket  = /mariadb/data/mariadb.sock
   user        = mariadb
8. Copy the init.d script from support files in the right location:
9. Edit /etc/init.d/mariadb replacing mysql with mariadb
10. Run mysql_install_db by explicitly giving it the my.cnf file as argument:

    scripts/mysql_install_db --defaults-file=/opt/mariadb-data/my.cnf

Although on step 10, I can't follow this command. So I did what I stated above and shown the error.

Comment: What are you trying to do? http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault

Comment: I am installing MariaDB on my server, but I don't want to remove mysql, yet. From the link provided above, I am about to install the server files as based on the my.cnf (Configuration file). I type that command and the problem shows up. @GioMac

Comment: please provide more info about your installation.

Comment: @GioMac Could you be specific on on what you are looking for?

Comment: What have you done so far, your distribution, etc

Comment: @GioMac I edited the original post to show my steps.

Answer (score 0):

`basedir` is "base" directory, where all `bin` `lib` etc directories reside.

Change  `basedir = /mariadb/mariadb` to `basedir = /mariadb`.

Also, I guess `my.cnf` location is somewhere at `/mariadb/data/my.cnf`, change `--defaults-file=/opt/mariadb-data/my.cnf` accordingly.

Also, `mysql_install_db` must run from `/mariadb` with `scripts/mysql_install_db`

`mysql_install_db` will call script from `/usr/bin`, not the one from `/mariadb/scripts/`.

It's better to follow standards and install it under `/opt/`.

Also, be sure selinux is in permissive mode:

`getenforce`

set "permissive" in `/etc/sysconfig/selinux`